# Check values in dataframe against another dataframe and append values if present

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
DF1
A   B   C
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9

DF2
Match   Values
1       a,d
7       b,c
```

I want to match DF1['A'] with DF2['Match'] and append DF2['Values'] to DF1 if the value exists

```
So my result will be:
A    B    C    Values
1    2    3    a,d
7    8    9    b,c
```

Now I can use the following code to match the values but it's returning an empty dataframe.

```
df1 = df1[df1['A'].isin(df2['Match'])]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit such that your dataframes are more clearly structured?

Comment: Have you tried `pd.merge()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing a lookup, you can do this in one step by merging the dataframes:

`pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='A', right_on='Match')`

Specify `how='inner'` if you only want records that appear in both, `how='left'` if you want all of df1's data.

If you want to keep only the Values column:

`pd.merge(df1, df2.set_index('Match')['Values'].to_frame(), how='inner', left_on='A', right_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks! that works, but if my DF2 has multiple columns, but I want to retain just one other column how would I go about it?

Comment: @Mohnish - are you looking to keep both Match and Values columns?

Comment: No, suppose DF@ has the columns 'Match', 'Values', 'Data', but I only want to retain 'Values'

Comment: See edits above. And please accept as answer if this answers your question! Thank you.

Comment: it shows memory error for  large dataframes(2M rows in each df)

Comment: what if there are repetitions in `Match` column?